# Getting video files value null while integrating with Vimeo Networking java Library, to play the video by URI

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android

I used [Vimeo Networking Library](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/tree/master)  in my android app to play the video by **Video View** by useing the official library of Vimeo.

I authenticate the API with Token

The problem with the code is that it gives me the **null** value for the **videoFiles**. When I give the link in **b** format mentioned below between the code comment

Here is my code

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.player);
// Getting access Token

        String accessToken = getString(R.string.access_token);
        Configuration.Builder configBuilder = new Configuration.Builder(accessToken)
                .enableCertPinning(false);
//Vimeo Client autenticated

        VimeoClient.initialize(configBuilder.build());
// the video uri; if you have a video, this is video.uri
```

I don't know which URI I should Pass, So I pass the URI in 2 format

a) https://player.vimeo.com/videos/123456789

It throws me the error from the failure method

> I/TAG5: Vimeo error  : Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

b) https://player.vimeo.com/videos/123456789/config

> I/TAG1: Video: com.vimeo.networking.model.Video@0
> I/TAG2: VideoFiles null

So finally I use link b

```
    final String uri = "https://player.vimeo.com/videos/123456789/config"; 
    GsonDeserializer gsonDeserializer = new GsonDeserializer();
    VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
        @Override
        public void success(Video video) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "Sucessful" + video, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("TAG1", "Video: " + video);


            ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.files;
            Log.i("TAG2", "VideoFiles " + videoFiles);
// I am getting null Value of **videoFiles** and it's not passing the if block with link b above mentioned 

            if (videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
                VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(0); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
                Log.i("TAG3", "VideoFiles " + videoFiles);
                String link = videoFile.getLink();
                Log.i("TAG4", "link " + link);
                // load link
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PlayActivity.this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(link));
                videoView.setMediaController(null);
                videoView.requestFocus();
                videoView.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(VimeoError error) {

            Log.i("TAG5", "vimeo error  : " + error.getErrorMessage());
            Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "failure due to " + error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the solution, thought of posting it here. So it can help other

The answer is straightforward, and I got the **videoFile** (TAG1) and **link** (TAG2) bypassing the link in this format

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789
```

So the final code will be like this

```
final String uri = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789";
```

instead of this

```
final String uri = "https://player.vimeo.com/videos/123456789/config";
```

Here is my complete code that helps me to play the video in android app by using Vimeo networking library

**Presenting the final code**

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.player);
    // Getting access Token

    String accessToken = getString(R.string.access_token);
    Configuration.Builder configBuilder = new Configuration.Builder(accessToken)
            .enableCertPinning(false);
    //Vimeo Client autenticated

    VimeoClient.initialize(configBuilder.build());
    // the video uri; if you have a video, this is video.uri

    final String uri = "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789"; 

    VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
    
    @Override
    public void success(Video video) {
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "Sucessful" + video, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       
        ArrayList<VideoFile> videoFiles = video.files;
        Log.i("TAG1", "videoFiles " + videoFiles);
        if (videoFiles != null && !videoFiles.isEmpty()) {
            VideoFile videoFile = videoFiles.get(0); // you could sort these files by size, fps, width/height
            
            String link = videoFile.getLink();
            Log.i("TAG2", "link " + link);
            // load link
            // use the link to play the video by **EXO Player** or **Video View**
           // Start your video player here
           }
         }

    @Override
    public void failure(VimeoError error) {

        Log.i("TAG3", "vimeo error  : " + error.getErrorMessage());
        Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, "failure due to " + error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: How to create link in this format : https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/123456789

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on library version 3.12.0 & it works:-

> Pls note that this access token needs to have all the three access to
> be check at the time of building it - "public", "private", "video
> file"

```
val confBuilder = VimeoApiConfiguration.Builder(accessToken)
val configuration = confBuilder.build()
Authenticator.initialize(configuration)
VimeoApiClient.initialize(configuration,Authenticator.instance())
VimeoApiClient.instance()
   .fetchVideo(finalUrl, null, null, null, object : VimeoCallback<Video>{
 //here url should be like "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}" otherwise it wasn't working whatever the url was
     override fun onError(error: VimeoResponse.Error) {
        Logger.d("TAG", "vimeo error = ${error.message}")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    override fun onSuccess(response: VimeoResponse.Success<Video>) {
      val video = response.data
      Log.d("TAG", "vimeo video user = ${response.data.user?.name}")
        val play: Play? = video.play
        val progressiveFiles: List<ProgressiveVideoFile>? = play.progressive
      val linkToMp4File: String? = progressiveFiles?.get(0)?.link
                                runExoplayer(linkToMp4File)
       }
      })
```

> In this Play data will be there iff the video is created by the same user whose access token you are using.
>
> You can verify this by comparing the user you are getting inside the video object (Logged above) with the user with
> which you have authenticated (shown below) :-

```
VimeoApiClient.instance().fetchCurrentUser(null, null, object : VimeoCallback<User>{
        override fun onError(error: VimeoResponse.Error) {

        }
        override fun onSuccess(response: VimeoResponse.Success<User>) {
            Logger.d("TAG", "vimeo user = ${response.data.name}")
        }
    })
```

> Only those videos will have Play data whose user is same as video
> creator/member on vimeo account as your access token owner.
> This is mentioned in the official document here https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication (Understanding the
> authentication process)