# Play Private Vimeo Video on Android-Vimeo-Player or Webview

Tags: android, webview, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I followed https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java to configure **Vimeo client**(initialized by that accesstoken) on **Android** using hardcoded **access token** (has access to public and private videos). but the call of ***VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchContent()*** fails.

```
public void vimeoSettings(){
    String urlPublic = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/496738949";
    String urlPrivate = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/496739025";

    Configuration.Builder confBuilder = new Configuration.Builder("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    //later will generate in runtime and whats the validity?

    Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build();
    VimeoClient.initialize(configuration);
    VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchContent(String.valueOf(Uri.parse(urlPublic)), CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class){
        @Override
        public void success(Video video) {
            if(video != null){
                Log.d("webviewactivity","inside vimeo settings - video not null ");
                Play play = video.getPlay();
                if (play != null) {
                    VideoFile dashFile = play.getDashVideoFile();
                    String dashLink = dashFile.getLink();
                    // load link

                    VideoFile hlsFile = play.getHlsVideoFile();
                    String hlsLink = hlsFile.getLink();
                    // load link

                    ArrayList<VideoFile> progressiveFiles = play.getProgressiveVideoFiles();
                    String linkToMp4File = progressiveFiles.get(0).getLink();
                    
                    webView.load(linkToMp4File);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(VimeoError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

facing these **Errors** :

```
E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.emergingit.emergingstudy/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.emergingit.emergingstudy/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
```

what are these errors indicate and, even if I solve this,

1. is this the **right approach** to load in Webview as I must have to make my **video private with domain restriction** for the website use case?
2. can I use this approach to play in https://github.com/ct7ct7ct7/Android-VimeoPlayer?

I am getting verified first by our token from the backend and then given the URL. after that using the access token and configuring the Vimeo client I need to load the video.
**Vimeo official documentation** for this kind of private video scenario for android seems really **unclear** to me and also contacted for help but did not get any response though I have a paid account.

Please help or suggest..!!

Comment: Hello @Nafiul, Did you find an answer ?

Comment: as far as I remember this problem was solved. please check out my other question-answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578764/how-to-integrate-vimeo-on-android-and-website-with-specific-user-access and let me know whether it solves the problem or not, then I will add it as the answer.