# Vimeo Networking Library Crash for Android 10 platform (api29)

Tags: runtime-error, android-10.0, sslsocketfactory, vimeo-android, trustmanager

I implemented vimeo networking using vimeo networking library(https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java), exoplayer and explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737556/8814924

Now the problem is when I was checking with API 30 it was getting error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emergingit.emergingstudy/com.emergingit.emergingstudy.activities.course.ExoPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on Android10Platform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on Android10Platform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl

which indicates the error on

```
VimeoClient.initialize(configuration);
```

which issue is dicscussed here : https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5878 , issue discussion :

```
I assume you are calling the deprecated form of sslSocketFactory, which is broken on newer Android versions. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L719

/**
 * Sets the socket factory used to secure HTTPS connections. If unset, the system default will
 * be used.
 *
 * @deprecated [SSLSocketFactory] does not expose its [X509TrustManager], which is a field that
 *     OkHttp needs to build a clean certificate chain. This method instead must use reflection
 *     to extract the trust manager. Applications should prefer to call
 *     `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)`, which avoids such reflection.
 */
@Deprecated(
    message = "Use the sslSocketFactory overload that accepts a X509TrustManager.",
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR
)
fun sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory) = apply {
  if (sslSocketFactory != this.sslSocketFactoryOrNull) {
    this.routeDatabase = null
  }

  this.sslSocketFactoryOrNull = sslSocketFactory
  this.certificateChainCleaner = Platform.get().buildCertificateChainCleaner(sslSocketFactory)
}
```

is there any solution possible with using the current version "1.1.3" of networking library for this or I have to wait till the library update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I primarily Solved the problem for Vimeo video streaming on the Android 10 platform using the Vimeo-Networking library (v1.1.3).
as the main problem is in the OkHttpClient build method

```
builder.sslSocketFactory(sSLSocketFactory);
//RetrofitClientBuilder.java#186
```

where with 1 parameter version is depricated and I needed to pass X509TTrustManager as 2nd parameter like this :

```
builder.sslSocketFactory(sSLSocketFactory, new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        });
```

So it solved my problem till this update comes in the stable version of this library. How I implemented this is described below :

1. Error was showing on **VimeoClient.initialize(accessToken);** line and I searched about the error and find out that it is caused because of this OkHttpClient method deprecation (with 1 parameter).
2. So I went into VimeoClient.java and saw in its constructor **private Retrofit createRetrofit()** was called and inside it **private OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient()** was called. and there **public class RetrofitClientBuilder** object was created and it's problemetic method was **public OkHttpClient build()** in which : `if (sSLSocketFactory != null) { builder.sslSocketFactory(sSLSocketFactory); }`
   this deprecated method was called.
3. So I just had to create 2 new java file with name **VimeoClientUpdated.java** and **RetrofitClientBuilderUpdated.java** which is just a renamed copy of **VimeoClient.java** and **RetrofitClientBuilder.java** and now my **RetrofitClientBuilderUpdated.java** has no deprecated method rather the correct and **VimeoClientUpdated.java** is calling **RetrofitClientBuilderUpdated.java**
   (I couldn't extend because of the final class and couldn't even wrap the class as to the gateway to that solution, I had to face the private method which wasn't possible to alter in wrapper class)
4. and finally just instead of calling `VimeoClient.initialize(accessToken)` I am calling my newly created `VimeoClientUpdated(accessToken)` which won't crash while playing Vimeo video on Android 10.

Suggest me if there is a better way of serving my purpose (solving deprecated library method calling from the android activity).
Cheers..!!

Comment: This disables security in your app.  The Vimeo library needs to stop calling the long deprecated  method that can't be supported on all platforms.

Comment: @YuriSchimke it disabled the security for the app? can you please elaborate a little...  as there was no other/updated version of the library and calling depricated method what is the way to restore security as I had to do that to make it working?

Comment: To build the sslSocketFactory you generally already have the real truatmanager anyway. Passing in a noop version just makes the connection insecure.